# Scala, library akka.actor

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to Scala actors and I do not get why my code isn't compiling.
Apparently '?' is not a member, I already imported the akka.actors.patern._ but it's still not working.
Could anyone clarify this dark thing a bit please?
Thanks !

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef}
import akka.pattern._

class Registry extends Actor {
  import Registry._
  var registry:Map[String, Any] = Map()
  def receive = {
    case Lookup(name) => sender ! registry.get(name)
  }
}

object Registry {
  import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
  case class Lookup(name: String)  
  // create dedicated actor infrastructure
  val system = ActorSystem("myActorInfrastructure")
  // create actor with a name and register it with the infrastructure
  def apply(name: String) = system.actorOf(Props(new Registry()), name) 
}

class Tweeter(val name: String, val regist:Registry, var followers:List[ActorRef]=List()) extends Actor{
    import Tweeter._
    def receive = {
      case Follow(user) => {
        //Here is the error
        (regist!? Lookup(name)) match{
        case Some(a:ActorRef) => a ! AddFollower(sender)
        }
      }
      case AddFollower(follower) => followers = follower::followers 
  }
}

object Tweeter {
    import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
  case class Follow(user: String)
  case class AddFollower(follower: ActorRef)
  def apply(name: String, annuaire:Registry) = Registry.system.actorOf(Props(new Tweeter(name,annuaire))) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve just changed the code to make it compile. I added some annotations to clarify:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef}
import akka.pattern._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Registry extends Actor {
  import Registry._
  var registry:Map[String, Any] = Map()
  def receive = {
    case Lookup(name) => sender ! registry.get(name)
  }
}

object Registry {
  import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
  case class Lookup(name: String)  
  // create dedicated actor infrastructure
  val system = ActorSystem("myActorInfrastructure")
  // create actor with a name and register it with the infrastructure
  def apply(name: String) = system.actorOf(Props(new Registry()), name) 
}

class Tweeter(val name: String, regist: ActorRef, var followers:List[ActorRef]=List()) extends Actor {
    import Tweeter._
    import Registry._

    implicit val timeout: Timeout = 3 seconds

    def receive = {
      case Follow(user) => {
        // regist must be an actor ref
        // Ask returns future, you have to map for pattern matching
        (regist ? Lookup(name)).map { _
          match {
            case Some(a:ActorRef) => a ! AddFollower(sender)
          }
        }
      }
      case AddFollower(follower) => followers = follower::followers 
  }
}

object Tweeter {

  import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
  case class Follow(user: String)
  case class AddFollower(follower: ActorRef)

  // Create the actor and use your reference
  val annuaire = Registry("registry")
  def apply(name: String, annuaire: ActorRef) = Registry.system.actorOf(Props(new Tweeter(name, annuaire))) 
}
```

Comment: In general it is better to use the actor system dispatcher to execute futures in actors on as it will have a lifecycle that is bound to the actor system - it will shutdown when the actor system does.